# UIWebView: Accessing HTML-Embedded Data During User Interaction

Tags: ios, uiwebview

**Scenario:**
1) User interact with web page via UIWebView.
2) Server returns embedded data (HTML-commented XML data) per user response.

**Problem:**
UIWebView's delegate method 'webViewDidFinishLoad' fires only once, during the initial load.  So I can't disseminate the UIWebView's contents per server's response to user input.

However, UIWebView's delegate method 'shouldStartLoadWithRequest' fires EVERY TIME the UIWebView refreshes/server response; but the refreshed html hasn't yet been loaded.

**Question:**
What's the simplest way to capture the HTML doc (with embedded data) per reload?

Again, the 'webViewDidFinishLoad' only *fires once*; unless a new http call is sent (either remotely via a re-direct, or from within Objective-C).

BTW: We're using JQuery Mobile to navigate between pages.